# How to deserialize Spring Boot actuator environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to deserialize the Spring Boot Environment object returned by:

http://hostname:port/actuator/env

I'm using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`:

```
private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
...
ClientResponse clientResponse = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
InputStream is = clientResponse.getEntityInputStream();

org.springframework.core.env.Environment e = mapper.readValue(is, org.springframework.core.env.Environment.class);
```

The code above fails with the following error, which makes sense:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.core.env.Environment, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
```

But I've tried all the implementations of the `Environment` class (`AbstractEnvironment`, `MockEnvironment`, `StandardEnvironment`, `StandardServletEnvironment`) and they all fail as well.

Which class should I use?

Comment: That isn't the environment object but a representation of what Spring Boot calls the environment. Trying to deserialize that into one of the `Environment` classes simply won't work.

Comment: That's interesting. So I'm basically wasting my time.

Comment: The `Environment` is a heavy and custom object to instantiate, especially the internal `PropertySource` instances. You cannot simply deserialize them.

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.core.env.Environment` is an interface. So `ObjectMapper` can not guess what concrete class to instantiate. You need to tell your `ObjectMapper` which class to use. So in your line 
`org.springframework.core.env.Environment e = mapper.readValue(is,org.springframework.core.env.Environment.class);` You need to replace `org.springframework.core.env.Environment.class` with some concrete class. For example `org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment` (depending on what kind of environment actually being returned). Otherwise de-serialize it to map:

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(is,HashMap<String, Object>.class);
```

And then go from there

Comment: Thank you guys. I don't have the source code of the service I'm trying to inspect, so I don't know what kind of environment is being returned. Looking at the json I would guess a StandardServletEnvironment: {"activeProfiles":["aaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbb"],"propertySources":[{"name":"server.ports","properties":{"local.server.port":{"value":50053}}},{"name":"servletContextInitParams","properties":{}},{"name":"systemProperties","properties":{"java.runtime.name":{"value":"Java(TM) SE Runtime...  Anyway, whether I use StandardServletEnvironment or StandardEnvironment I get the same error:

Comment: Can not deserialize instance of org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@67f9fca4; line: 1, column: 42] (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment["propertySources"])